# Whole map layer transparent in MapServer 6

Tags: transparency, mapserver

I have a mapfile with several layers, one of which has an OFFSITE set to 255 255 255. Unfortunately this seems to be causing transparency in all layers when the mapfile is called as a wms layer - the background map (an independent wms call) is showing through, although strangely not through the white sections, but seems to be more related to the anti-aliasing (when I switch IMAGEMODE to RGB rather than RGBA, the problem goes away, but the image quality is terrible).

When I comment out the OFFSITE the transparency across all layers is removed.
If I use Mapserver 5.x instead of 6, the problem doesn't occur either.

But neither of these solutions is an option for me.

Strangely, the problem doesn't occur in ArcGIS 10, but it does in QGIS and OpenLayers and MapModeller (CadCorp), but I can't see an obvious difference in the wms call from these different clients.

I am a bit unclear about all the other transparency settings available in Mapserver, but I have changed some of these (wms_bgcolor and wms_transparent in metadata; TRANSPARENT ON/OFF in OUTPUTFORMAT) and none have made a difference.

I hope somebody can help shed some light...

Thanks in advance,
Fiona